# CollapsingToolbarLayout with RelativeLayout issue below KitKat 4.4 OS

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have create layout with combination of  AppBarLayout > CollapsingToolbarLayout > RelativeLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCoverImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutImgWrapper"
                android:layout_width="74dp"
                android:layout_height="74dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_normal_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rest_image_wrapper"
                android:padding="3dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRestaurant"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                    />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <com.test.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layoutImgWrapper"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layoutImgWrapper"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layoutImgWrapper"
                android:text="Benjy's"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:typeface="fonts/proximanova_semibold.ttf" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvRestaurantName"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layoutImgWrapper"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layoutImgWrapper"

                />

            <com.test.widget.UnderlinedTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReviews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ratingBar"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:text="0 Review"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:underlineColor="@color/rest_review_underline_color"
                app:underlineWidth="1dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary_dark_color"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tab_indicator_height"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

[image]
[image]

When I re-expanding layout, top part (toolbar, tab etc) is not working in ICS and jelly bean. I have tested, It was working above all versions. **I think top part height is fixed after collapsing (it takes toolbar's height) in lower OS.** Let me suggest any solution.
Thanks in advance.